# Transition within Navigation to the Root Tab Bar Controller XCODE

Tags: xcode, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard, uitabbarcontroller, swift5

I have an issue of moving from a ViewController back to a root tab bar controller. Here's my storyboard, I have attached an image of my issue.

[image: storyboard]

I have tried the following:

```
let homeTBC = controllers![3] as! UITabBarController
        let homeVC = homeTBC.viewControllers?[0] as! HomeViewController
        self.present(homeVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

I'm getting this error message:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Application tried to present modally a view controller <ITEiOSApp.HomeViewController: 0x7fbb200bf000> that has a parent view controller <UITabBarController: 0x7fbb200bea00>.'
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Please help really running out of options here.

Thank you in advance

Comment: I did tried to print ```print(self.navigationController?.viewControllers)``` and got the following output: ```Optional([<ITEiOSApp.LoginEnrollViewController: 0x7fb141707310>, <ITEiOSApp.ViewController: 0x7fb141713f30>, <ITEiOSApp.ShowServicesTVC: 0x7fb14143a480>, <UITabBarController: 0x7fb14185bc00>, <ITEiOSApp.ShowPaymentAccountViewController: 0x7fb141747450>, <ITEiOSApp.AddCardViewController: 0x7fb142809400>, <ITEiOSApp.PaymentSuccessViewController: 0x7fb1420b8600>])

Comment: I wanted to be able to pop the ```UITabBarController``` and show the first View Controller on this Tab Bar but it seems for some reason I am unable to do so